# Where is my database file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, nunit, connection-string

I have an MVC3 web application with a local database under App_Data/ASPNETDB.MDF. I also have an integration test project that I'm using to run NUnit against.  It has some tests reading from the database.  I copied the connection string from the MVC project's web.config to the test project's app.config.  Both projects use Entity Framework Code First.

My site runs great. My tests run great.  But the data is different in both projects.  Ergo ... they're using different databases, right?

```
<head scratch="true">
    <puzzledLook />
</head>
```

My questions

1. Are they really different databases?
2. Where is the database file for the test project?  I can't find it.

Comment: 'Where is the database file' - LOL! I'm sorry, but..  It would be even funnier if I hadn't had the same issue myself on occasions:)

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for it to be answerable.  You've overlooked something in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Test run creates a test folder. Is your database file marked to copy to output directory? In that case could you not add

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

to any of your unit tests?

Comment: Great suggestion, but there were no databases there. Still, +1 for a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer above is about right although I would use
   Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]

An example for my test project would be 
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide\

I seem to recall that the AppData folder is copied to the location of the exe so that it can find the data when it is running

The issue is caused because the unit tests are run by a separate executable called VSTestHost.exe